# Selecting "favourite tags" under for new questions doesn't fetch any question

Tags: bug, status-deferred, new-nav

On the new navigation, I selected my Favourite tags, and that doesn't seem to return any questions:

[image]

This is the URL generated:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&tagFilter=favorite
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&tags=apex%20cvs%20golang%20linux%20notepad%2b%2b%20oracle10g%20oracle11g%20oracle9i%20oracleforms%20oracle-xe%20plsqldeveloper%20python%20ruby%20sinatra%20sqldeveloper%20virtualbox%20visual-studio-2008&mode=any

Steps:

- Head to the home page
- Under the new tag, select favourite tags - no questions returned
- Switched from newest to newest to recent activity - still no questions returned
- Switched back to newest - now it fetches the questions

Comment: It's a timeout...

Answer (score 1):

It's a timeout issue, as noted in the release post.